# [UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, nsmutabledictionary

```
    func createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles: [NSString]) -> UIView {
    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    let keyboardRowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
    var dict = [UIButton:String]()
    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles 
    {
       let button = createButtonWithTitle(title: buttonTitle as String)
        buttons.append(button)
        keyboardRowView.addSubview(button)
        dict.updateValue("\(buttonTitle)", forKey: button)
    }
    allButtons = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dict)
    //error:[UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e011bc0
    addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons: buttons, mainView:keyboardRowView)
    return keyboardRowView
}
```

I am new to iOS, I want to create a `NSMutableDictionary` of `UIButton` but it give the following error:

> Cannot cast 'UIButton' to 'NSCopying'.

I don't understand why this error occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift?

Comment: revert it `var dict = [UIButton:String]()` to `var dict = [String:UIButton]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really not certain why you would have to resort to using `NSString` or `NSMutableArray`, especially taking into account that you bridge `NSString` to `String`, which hints that `NSString` is actually useless.

Local `buttons` and `dict` arrays also seem to be unnecessary since after your loop finishes you simply assign those buttons to `allButtons`. It means that you can address that storage directly (with proper Swift `[String: UIButton]` type instead of `NSMutableDictionary`):

```
var allButtons: [String: UIButton]!

func createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles: [String]) -> UIView {

    let keyboardRowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))

    // Initialize / reset dictionary
    // Do it here or on declaration
    allButtons = [String: UIButton]()

    // Populate dictionary
    buttonTitles.forEach { title in
        let button = UIButton()// createButtonWithTitle(title: title)
        keyboardRowView.addSubview(button)
        allButtons[title] = button
    }

    addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons: Array(allButtons.values),
                                   mainView: keyboardRowView)
    return keyboardRowView
}
```

You also access buttons by their titles, not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton` does not conform to the `NSCopying` `protocol` and so you cannot use it as a key in `NSDictionary`

From Apple docs:

> The key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must conform to the
>   NSCopying protocol).

Reference: pheelicks answer of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820366/nsmutabledictionary-with-uibutton-as-keys-iphone-development)